# C# - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

```
 public static void CopyImage(Image picToSave, string name)
    {
        if (picToSave.Source != null)
        {
            BitmapImage src = (BitmapImage)picToSave.Source;
            if (!Directory.Exists("Images"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("Images");
            }

            FileStream stream = new FileStream("Images/" + name + ".jpg", FileMode.Create);
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }



    }
```

The problem occurs when i choose a file which already exists in the /Images directory, i guess it just cant overwrite, The exception is thrown at the "FileStream"" line (FileMode.Create I guess).

If i Choose a file which isn't in the /Images directory it works fine and copies the file to the Images Directory like it should..

Thank you :)

Comment: how do you load your images into Image objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How did you load the image in the first place? If you didn't change the default value for `CacheOption`, the file is locked by the `BitmapImage` object. You need to specify `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = imageUri;
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.EndInit();
```

Comment: My image is "Image" Type and not BitmapImage so I can't use all this, is there a way for "Image" type?

Comment: Thanks Thomas :) I had a similar issue and you were the only one pointing to the real issue. I wanted to delete an image displayed in an image control. Till I saw your post I was trying to make the image source as null and then do System.GC.Collect() etc, but after I saw your post I realized that the problem was with the way I loaded the image initially!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you created Bitmaps from all the images in the image folder this sounds like a known problem with the Bitmap class - it keeps a file lock on the file you created it from until you call dispose. Also see this thread: [.NET app locks file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188464/net-app-locks-file).

Hans Passant offers the following workaround in this thread:     [Loading a file to a Bitmap but leaving the original file intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386749/loading-a-file-to-a-bitmap-but-leaving-the-original-file-intact)

```
public static Image LoadImageNoLock(string path) {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path))) {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognize "FromStream"

Comment: you need a reference to System.Drawing to use the Image class as in your sample - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx

Comment: The OP is using WPF, which doesn't use System.Drawing (the Image class in the code is System.Windows.Controls.Image). Anyway, you don't need to load the image into a MemoryStream. You can just open a FileStream, load the image from it, and close the stream

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I would post something that worked for me from @Thomas Levesque's comment.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open);
Image image = new Image();
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = stream;
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.EndInit();
image.Source = bi;
image.Height = 15;
btn.Content = image;
stream.Close();
stream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with some modifications in your code

set the write permission to your opened file

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("Images/" + name + ".jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```